# Time needed for full device encryption on Android L with 128GB microSD Card

Tags: cyanogenmod, 5.0-lollipop, encryption

So last night I decided to enable full device encryption on my Android L device (Sony Z3 compact running CM12). Right as I started I realized I had forgotten to unmount and eject the microSD card. I wasn't sure if it would encrypt the SD card, but the screen was still dark after I woke up and I assume that it is.

The microSD card is completely full (has 90% of my music collection on it). Since there's no status indicator during the encryption phase, I was wondering how much longer my phone would be out of commission? I'm hoping it won't take more than 24 hours, but that is a lot of storage and microSD cards can be pretty slow.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the device wasn't actually encrypting. After a day I reset the device and it rebooted fine. The device is rooted and I've read some places that full device encryption doesn't always work correctly on rooted devices. Also the encryption process apparently has an indicator too (I think?) and my screen was just blank the entire time.